# In Excel How can I sum (or perform any operation) total sum values of various columns when the column name is mentioned in a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a set of Data having 6 columns under different headers.
In sheet 2 we select some variables from Data sheet (to perform sum operation in this case).

**Whenever the user inputs some or all variables (Fruits, Veggies, Drinks, Snacks, Vegan, Dairy)from Data (sheet1) in to sheet 2 for items_chosen under Formula column (e.g Veggies + Drinks + Vegan) , then the output column(sheet 2) should display sum total of these selected columns, under Results.**

**example:** We chose, (Veggies + Snacks + Dairy) ;

Now total of each of these columns are 1222(veggies) , 1927(snacks) , 328(dairy)  ;

So in sheet 2 under result ,it should display = 3447 which is the sum total of [1222(veggies) + 1927(snacks) + 328(dairy)]

I know we can use Indirect function in excel but how can I take input from what is written in **Choose Variables here** column in sheet 2

**Sample Data:**

| Fruits | Veggies | Drinks | Snacks | Vegan | Dairy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 4 |
| 23 | 31 | 26 | 34 | 71 | 45 |
| 45 | 51 | 93 | 72 | 353 | 41 |
| 67 | 134 | 56 | 81 | 431 | 155 |
| 89 | 42 | 242 | 457 | 513 | 19 |
| 111 | 61 | 574 | 541 | 54 | 15 |
| 133 | 46 | 426 | 156 | 135 | 17 |
| 155 | 522 | 264 | 166 | 351 | 18 |
| 177 | 332 | 624 | 413 | 54 | 14 |

**Output:**

| Label | Choose Variables here |  |  |  | Output | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Items_chosen | Veggies + Snacks + Dairy |  |  |  | Result of Items_chosen |  |

Comment: What is `Label` and what is `Formula` in second screenshot? Post sample data as text so that we can copy.

Comment: @Harun24HR Ignore the header name Label, I just used it like that. And the Formula header denotes the operation we are performing under that cell, which in this case is sum

Comment: Harun24HR is it fine now?

Comment: It is fine now. try my answer.

Comment: @Harun24HR could you tell me what are some good resources to learn Excel from? or where did you learned it from

Comment: One good resource is https://exceljet.net/formulas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:F10)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1:F1,I3))))
```

[image]